# Can I say "I like you while you do me?" to say you like me too?

Tags: grammar

can I replace like with do as one can replaces all(?) verbs with do to make them shorter?

Answer (score 1):

NO, don't say this.

*To do X* when X is a personal pronoun is a euphemism for "to have sex with X."

Say "I like you the same way" or "I like you just as much."